# How to add prefix to socket.io logs redirected to winston?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, winston

In my node.js application I successfully redirect log messages produced by a [socket.io](http://socket.io/) library to a [winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston) library:

```
var express = require('express')
  , winston = require('winston')
  , http = require('http');
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    // ... configuring transports ...
  ]
});
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server, {'logger': logger});
```

Now I would want to add a prefix (something like "socket.io: ") to all these redirected messages for distinguishing them from log messages produced by other parts of the application. Is there a way how to achieve this?

Comment: This isn't a question specific to socket.io, probably better if revising the question title by leaving only Winston. Socket.io, in this case, is only the example

Answer (score 6):

Add label in logger transports.

```
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({
      json : false,
      timestamp : true,
      label: "socket.io:"
    })
  ]
});
```

Log messages will look like this -

```
2013-08-30T08:26:52.703Z - info: [socket.io:] socket.io started
2013-08-30T08:26:52.705Z - info: [socket.io:] hello
```

Check here more logging options with winston - https://github.com/flatiron/winston

Comment: Do I understand correctly that I must create a separate logger only for socket.io messages and use another logger for everything else? I would prefere using only one logger if possible.

Comment: You are not using separate logger for socket.io. When you do `require('socket.io')...{'logger': logger});` you are telling socket.io to use winston logger. You can use same winston logger anywhere in your node app.

Comment: OK, but I want to add prefix only to socket.io messages, not to all messages sent to winston. I don't know, how could I remove/change the label in `logger.log("info", "app started");`.

Comment: You can create categories for that. Check here https://github.com/flatiron/winston#working-with-multiple-loggers-in-winston

Comment: I think that `winston.loggers.add('category1', {...});` creates a new logger. And I'm not sure if writing to one file from more loggers/categories is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a following function

```
var winston = require('winston');

// Add prefix function
winston.prefix = function (filename)
{
    var label = '[' + path.parse(filename).name + ']';
    var override = function (lvl) {
        return function () {
            var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
            if (args[0]) {
                if (typeof(args[0]) === 'string')
                    args[0] = label + ' ' + args[0];
                else
                    args.unshift(label);
            }
            winston[lvl].apply(null, args);
        };
    };
    var log = { };
    for (var lvl in winston.levels) {
        log[lvl] = override(lvl);
    }
    return log;
}
```

And then in each module

```
var log = require('winston').prefix(__filename);
log.debug('hello');
```

or

```
var log = require('winston').prefix('socket_io');
log.debug('hello');
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't Winston specific but a generalized JS solution to prefixing and middleware...

```
var log = console.log;
function x(){ // optionally pass in post/pre fix here
  // caution do not put (var log = console.log()) here, the arguments will build up [ arg1 ] -> [ [arg1] , arg2 ] -> [ [ [ arg1 ] , arg2] , arg3 ] 
  console.log = function () {
        var args = Array.from(arguments);
        args.push('post fix');
        log.apply(console, args);
    }
}

new x()
console.log(1)
new x()
console.log(2)

OUTPUTS: 
1 post fix
2 post fix
```

OR better yet...

```
const log = console.log;
export default function middleWare(event) { // optionally pass in post/pre fix here
    console.log = (...args) => {
        log(...args, event.id);
    }
}
```